# Cant get Multi array working in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n=0;
int a[n], i;
int multi_array[n][3];
FILE *point = fopen("example.txt", "r");

fscanf(point,"%d" , &n);
printf("This is n: %d " , n);


for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    fscanf( point , "%d," , &multi_array[n][3]);
}

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n" , multi_array[n][3]);
}
}
```

The "example.txt" file has as code as following:

3

1,10,0

2,1,2

3,2,6

The first digit determines the number of array (n) and the bottom three rows of numbers are to be stored into those array, for example: 1,10,0 should be stored in first array and 2,1,2 stored in the second array and so on.

my above code gives me a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Your compiler didn't warn about the zero-length array?

Comment: Segmentation fault is your code's way of saying **open the debugger**.

Comment: Move `int a[n], i;` and `int multi_array[n][3];` lines past the line with the first `fscanf`, and try again. Do you see why this should work?

Comment: it's because when you are declaring the arrays using `n` the value of `n` is `0` so your array length is `0` but you're trying to inject `3` elements and there's no space for them thus *segmentation fault*

Comment: BTW, it seems to me that you will now know how many numbers to work with. It may be `3` or `30`. Consider using dynamic allocation after reading the first line.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight depends if he has a `C99` compiler (hopefully yes)

Comment: @AhmedMasud Oh, I also hope that in 2017 most programmers did switch over to C99.

Comment: Thanks EOF, dasblinkenlight, Ahmed Masud.

Comment: Just one more question, when i print n it gives me two values 3 and 0. i just need 3 why does it give 0 aswell?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans, 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}',  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when call any of the `scanf()` family of functions (for instance `fscanf()`), always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: arrays are indexed starting with 0 through (number of elements in array -1)  so this statement: `fscanf( point , "%d," , &multi_array[n][3]);` is indexing past the end of the array.  The result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know ahead of time how many rows your array is going to need, you cannot declare it on the stack (ie., `int a[n]` and `int multi_array[n][3]` are not going to work).  C does not resize the arrays for you when you change the value of n; you have declared them as size 0 and they remain that way, which is why you get SEGVs when you try to dereference them.

If you switch to calloc() and declare as `int *multi_array[3]`, things should work better for you.

You also have a bug in your printf() and fscanf() in that you are only ever dereferencing the last element in the array, not all three of them.  You have a further bug in that you are actually dereferencing the element one beyond the end, as an array of 3 elements has elements [0], [1], and [2].

Comment: They aren't going to work in the code shown because `n` is `0` at the time they're declared.  If the declarations were placed after `n` is read and validated (oops…it isn't validated; oh well, after it is read and the newly added validation code blesses it).  C allows variable length arrays (VLAs) in C99 and usually in C11; it just requires the length to be non-zero (and non-negative).  GCC may be less fussy about the zero length arrays; add `-pedantic` to the compilation options to get it to complain about them and other abuses of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
fscanf( point , "%d," , &multi_array[n][3]);
```

should be:

```
if( 3 != fscanf( point, :"%d,%d,%d", 
                 &multi_array[i][0],
                 &multi_array[i][1],
                 &multi_array[i][2] ) )
{ // then fscanf failed
    fprintf( stderr, "failed to read all 3 integers on data line: %d\n". i);
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fscanf successful
```

also, when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Similar to:

```
FILE *point = fopen("example.txt", "r");
if( !point )
{
    perror( "fopen to read 'example.txt' failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen successful
```

When the size of an array is determined by a value read in rather than a hard coded value, place all statements that use that size to declare an array AFTER the point where the size is read in.  That way the compiler can produce code to allocate the desired size.  Note: such arrays are called `VLAs`  (Variable Length Arrays)

To avoid compiler warnings about unused variables (and to save space on the stack) always remove unused arrays, I.E. remove this line:

```
int a[n],
```

It is best practice to keep data definitions local to where those data definitions are used.

Code should cleanup after itself.  It is poor programming practice to expect the OS to cleanup after sloppy code.

'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  The posted code contains the magic number '3'.  It is best if 'magic' numbers are given meaningful names and those meaningful names used throughout the code.  This is normally done by `#define` statements or a `enum` statement.

When a system function indicates an error occurred, then the global variable 'errno' is set with an appropriate value.  'errno' should be used to display the related text.  there are two ways to do this:

```
perror( "your error message" );
```

and

```
#include <errno.h>
...
fprintf( stderr, "the call to xxx returned the following error: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
```

The following code demonstrates all the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fscanf(), perror(), printf(), fprintf(), stderr, fclose(), fopen()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define NUM_DATA_PER_LINE 3

int main( void )
{
    int n;

    FILE *point = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if( !point )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read 'example.txt' failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( 1 != fscanf(point,"%d" , &n) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "fscanf failed to read the count of data lines" );
        fclose( point );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fscanf successful

    printf("This is n: %d " , n);

    int multi_array[n][ NUM_DATA_PER_LINE ];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if( NUM_DATA_PER_LINE != fscanf( point , "%d,%d,%d",
            &multi_array[i][0],
            &multi_array[i][1],
            &multi_array[i][2]) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "fscanf failed to read 3 items from data line: %d\n", i );
            fclose( point );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fscanf successful
    }

    fclose( point );

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for( int j=0; j < NUM_DATA_PER_LINE; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\n" , multi_array[i][j] );
        }
    }
}
```